# Как в android studio сделать форматирование стилей как в stackoverflow?

Tags: android, шрифты

Я получаю текст из `SQLite` и мне нужно вывести его в `TextView` с разными стилями. Я решил сделать как в `stackoverflow`, то есть если две звездочки в начале и в конце нужного фрагмента, то шрифт жирный, если одна - то курсив, три - курсив с жирным. Как мне теперь обработать получаемый текст и вывести в `TextView` уже отформатированным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите какой-нибудь урок по основам `HTML` тегов, а затем, текст который в БД обработайте тегами как вам нужно, и когда получаете из БД пропускайте через `HTML` в `TextView`.

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);

myText.setText(Html.fromHtml(<b>Это будет жирный текст</b>));
```

В скобках `fromHtml` передаете ссылку на обработанный тегами текст из БД